# How can I combine rewrite and client_max_body_size in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want to enable large file uploads to a single location, and that location is then rewritten to another location. It seems that the rewrite is resetting the other configurations.

My Config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www;
    index index.php;

    # this location requires large file upload
    location /upload {
        client_max_body_size 512M;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;
    }

    # all other locations
    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FPM
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/includes/php;
    }
}
```

If I move the client_max_body_size out of the `location` and into the `server`, then it works.

If I put it in both the `location /upload` AND `location ~ \.php$`, then it also works. But I don't want other locations to be able to upload large files.

I was thinking I could direct to PHP directly in the `location /upload`, but once I run the rewrite it will look for another location anyway. Does that mean I would have to have two separate locations for php scripts? Is there any way to make the `client_max_body_size` retain through other locations after the rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a specific `client_max_body_size` it needs to be set within (or inherited by) the `location` that processes the final URI. In your case, that is `location ~ \.php$`.

As you indicate in your question, the simplest solution is to process the PHP file in `location /upload`. This is easy to achieve, as you already have the PHP configuration in a separate include file.

Either a `rewrite ... break;` or overriding two of the `fastcgi_param` directives should work for you:

Option 1:

```
location /upload {
    client_max_body_size 512M;

    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 break;

    include /etc/nginx/includes/php;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Option 2:

```
location /upload {
    client_max_body_size 512M;

    include /etc/nginx/includes/php;

    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    request=$uri&$query_string;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! The first one appears to be working! I thought that the redirect would cause it to go into a loop, but I guess when it hits the fcgi_pass in the include that terminates it.

Comment: actually, i take that back. I still had my max body size in the php location. I turned on the debug log and it appears the php include which has 'fastcgi_pass' gets ignored, and the rewrite started to test all conditions again. Here is the debug log: https://gist.github.com/macdabby/13832f4257a73f82c01c. I'll try something with the params, but that didn't seem to work either.